# How to combine 1D arrays to make a new array

Tags: python, arrays, vector

I have set

```
x = data_array[:,0].astype(numpy.float)
```

This means it is one column of numbers. I have a similar thing for y. I need to combine these columns into 1 single array where column 1 is x and column 2 is y. How can I do this?

I have tried the reverse of my first step i.e.:

```
data[:,0] = x
```

but it did not like this!

```
data_array_new = numpy.array
data_array_new[:,0] = x
data_array_new[:,1] = y

print(data_array_new)

data_array_new[:,0] = x
```

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item          assignment

Comment: `data_array_new = numpy.array` is incorrect. `numpy.array` is a *function* used to create arrays, not an array itself, so `data_array_new` is also a *function*, not an array. You probably meant to do something like `data_array_new = numpy.array([...])`, where `[...]` is a stand-in for the intended contents of the array. This is why the array assignment `data_array_new[:,0] = x` gives you a `TypeError`: you're attempting to do an array assignment to something that isn't an array.

Comment: Use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) i.e. `np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)`

Comment: The reason you got your error btw is because `data_array_new = numpy.array` you are assigning the method instead of calling the initialiser. i.e. you should have done this: `data_array_new = numpy.array()`. That would then give you an index error so if you really want to do it your way (instead of the correct way which is to use concatenate) then you need to preallocate the array like this: `data_array_new = np.zeros(data.shape[0], 2)`

Answer (score 0):

With indexation you can do :

```
new_data_array = data_array[:,[0,1]]
```

To get columns 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
new_data=np.array([data[:,0],data[:,1]])
```

If I have the following array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Here are the various options:

```
np.array([data[:,0],data[:,1]])
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8]])

data[:,[0,1]]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])

data[[0,1],:]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

and many more possibilities.